# passing regex to path prop of Route works with warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
              <Route exact path={/^\/+$/g}>
                <Redirect to="/home" />
              </Route>
```

does work but:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` supplied to `Route`.
Route@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:789274:29
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:666:79
Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:785880:15
```

Are we not supposed to pass a regex to `path`?

Comment: Seems not. What routing/navigation library (and version) are you using, so we can confirm/validate the passed props? Looks like `react-router-dom`.

Comment: It is `react-router-dom`, not sure about the version. If not allowed, then how to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: It should be a string, or an array of strings, depending on version, which you seem to be using v4/5 syntax of. Are you just trying to redirect from "/" to "/home"? Or "//" or "///"? What is an actual path you are trying to match?

Comment: If it's React Router, the `path` attribute should be a string: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#route

Comment: @Drew Reese yeah, just match any number of `/` and then redirect to home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-router-dom [path](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) props use [path-to-rexexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0). The `path` prop can be either a string or an array of strings.

If I'm not mistaken you are wanting to match and redirect from any path with one or more `"/"` repeated characters (`"/"`, `"//"`, `"///"`, etc...). For this the path would be `"/+"`. You can also specify the `from` prop on the `Redirect` component so there's no need to be matched in a `Route` first if used inside a `Switch`.

[path-to-regexp one-or-more](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#one-or-more)

```
<Redirect from="/+" to="/home" />
```

Note the `Redirect` `to` prop takes ***only*** a string.

[Redirect](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: didn't even realize that you can just use `Redirect` without `Route`